# Use people results to show only users having access to current site collection

Tags: office-365, search-results, filter, search-scope, people-search

We've an Office365 site with more than 30K people using it, and we are using people search to show these users. This shows all the users in the tenant. But we need to show only people having access to the site collection. currently we used a custom profile property to filter the users, but i'm thinking there could be a way to show only the users who have access to current site collection. Is it possible?

Comment: Use the user information list? If you grant permission to a user, i think that user will be stored  in the site collection user information list .

Comment: Thankyou for the reply @uberz91. Yes, but the problem is I want to have the userprofile properties (ex:Depaartment, custom properties) as refiners and those values will not be there in User information list.